# Resolving a Promise and storing the value to be used in multiple other JS functions

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am importing a package that has some functions that returns a promise of the credentials I'm requesting. The keys are being used in multiple files - so I'm thinking I resolve the promise in one file and then export the values to all the other dependent files.

Fetching the credential file: getEmailKey.js

```
import {getKey} from '@secret.pkg'
export default class KeysService {
  constructor() {
    this.emailKey = null;
  }

  get emailKey () {
    return this.emailKey || this.fetchEmailKey();
  }

  async fetchEmailKey() {
    const key = await getKey;
    this.emailKey = key;
  }
```

Using the key: helperFunctions.js

```
import KeysService from './getEmailKey.js';
export function createEmailLink() {
  return `${BASE_URL}?key=${KeysService.emailKey}`
}
```

With this approach, the first time KeysService.emailKey is called, it will call this.fetchEmailKey(), but nothing will be returned as this.emailKey isn't set yet. Is there another approach where I don't need to wrap every function that needs the key to resolve the promise?

Comment: Every potential consumer will *have* to support asynchronity - there's no way around that.

Comment: The usual way to solve this is to do something like `this.promiseKey = getKey()` and then anyone who needs the key does `this.promiseKey.then(...)`.  You're caching the promise.  Then, every piece of code that wants the key gets it the same way, whether they are the first to request it or the last.  Anyone who requests it after the promise is already resolved will just immediately get the value in their `.then()` handler with no waiting, but the calling code does not have to care one way or the other.

Comment: if you think about what this does `return this.emailKey || this.fetchEmailKey();` - it returns either the value in `this.emailKey` or the **Promise** returned by `fetchEmailKey()` - (note: the promise that is returned will resolve to `undefined` anyway) - so, you'll return either a value or a Promise - the fact that you can return two different things should scream *this is not correct code* at you :p

Comment: Or, you could get the key once as part of your initialization and not finish initializing whatever it is this is until you have to key so they it can be cached and available for anyone who might request it before any code can ask for it.